# I need to split a String into 3 parts with different sizes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, string.h

So, i have to do a Glossary, the scanf will always read one char and some text, the first char is the action that i need to do, like erase something, include or print. The other part is the word that i will add or remove and all the rest is the meaning. 
Sometimes i will recieve only the char for action, for like "print all", or i can recieve something like "e word meaning meaning" to delete the meaning, but i can also recieve "e word" and erease the word and meaning associated, so the entry is not always the same size.
The entry cases are:

```
i word meaning
q word
e word
e word meaning
p
```

with "meaning" beeing a string like "has a red color"

I tried to use strtok and strcat to get it together for the meaning, but no success, this code that i left here are just an exemple, i know that doens't work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char str[] = "a bbbbbbbbbb cccc ccccccccccc cccc"; 
    char* temp; 
    char* rest = str; 
    int i = 0;

    char op[2];

    while ((temp = strtok_r(rest, " ", &rest))){
        printf("%s ", temp);
        if (i>=2){
            strcat(op[2],temp);
        }
        op[i]=temp;
        i++;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

action: a 
word: bbbbbbbbbb 
meaning: cccc ccccccccccc cccc

Comment: Will `a` always be a single character? Will `bbbbbbbbbb` always be 10 characters? Then it's easy to copy only those bits out from the string. Especially if you remember that e.g. `str` is equal to `&str[0]`.

Comment: Your specification is incomplete, as "to split" is ambiguous. What do you need to do with the "split" strings?

Comment: @Guerezi The array op is not initialized so this call strcat(op[2],temp); (apart of it is incorrect) has undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Not to mention that index `2` is out of bounds, or that `op[2]` is not a string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I also saw this when I was writing my comment.:)

Comment: @Guerezi What is supposed to do this instruction "e word"?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, "e word" will erase the node word from a tree, including the meaning associeted with that node. Thanks for the help, but for now i finded a way to test the code, is not beautiful and i NEED to make better, but for now it wil work, i basicly added an for(i<3) and a If, if i==0 then action, if ==1 then word and if ==2 then meaning, and i stoped using arrays for now.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `bbbbbbbbbb` do not contain spaces, call `strtok()` 3 times:

```
char str[] = "a bbbbbbbbbb cccc ccccccccccc cccc"; 
char *op[3];  // Changed to char * and increased size

// Note: the last call to strok changes the delimiter
if (NULL != (op[0] = strtok(str, " "))) {
    if (NULL != (op[1] = strtok(NULL, " "))) {
        if (NULL != (op[2] = strtok(NULL, ""))) {
            printf("%s / %s / %s\n", op[0], op[1], op[2]);
        }
   }
}
```

Output

> a / bbbbbbbbbb / cccc ccccccccccc cccc

Or, if you prefer all in one line:

```
if ((op[0] = strtok(str, " ")) && (op[1] = strtok(NULL, " ")) && (op[2] = strtok(NULL, ""))) {
    printf("%s / %s / %s\n", op[0], op[1], op[2]);
}
```